# How to reference Windows.Devices.WiFi namespace in F#?

Tags: .net, windows, f#, wifi

I'm having trouble to reference this namespace, I cannot find it the available references. There is little information out there on this namespace. Is it only available on older version of .NET Framework or something?

Comment: Windows.Devices.WiFi belongs to UWP SDK, are you creating UWP application?

Comment: @NicklausBrain Oh, how can I create a UWP project? I don't see that option in VS 2019.

Comment: please checkout here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/get-set-up

Comment: @BentTranberg Did you read it? It is very much related to F#. I have found now that F# does not support UWP apps.

Comment: I agree, that's relevant, and I had forgotten about that. Unfortunately my initial comment appears to have vanished for reasons unknown, I suspect bad moderation, but I guess most understand my initial comment was simply that I didn't believe this was related to F#.